# Mysql can't update json for the first time

Tags: mysql, node.js, json

**Router express**

```
router.get("/winner", async function (req, res, next) {
  let id = Number(req.query.id);
  let fileUrlId = req.query.fileUrlId;

  if (!id && !fileUrlId) {
    return res.send(failModel(2004, false, null));
  }

  const resGetWC = await getCurrentFileUrl(id);
  if (resGetWC.length === 1) {
    const tempFileUrl = JSON.parse(resGetWC[0].fileUrl).reduce((result, item) => {
      if (item.id === fileUrlId) {
        item.winnerCount = item.winnerCount ? item.winnerCount + 1 : 1;
      }
      result.push(item);
      return result;
    }, []);

    const resultUpdate = await updateWinner(id, JSON.stringify(tempFileUrl));

    if (resultUpdate?.affectedRows === 1) {
      return res.send(successModel());
    }
    return res.send(failModel(-1, false, null));
  }

  return res.send(failModel(-1, false, null));
});
```

**updateWinner**

```
const updateWinner = async (id, fileUrl) => {
  const resultGet = await getCurrentWinnerCount(id);
  if (resultGet.length === 1) {
    const sql = `
      UPDATE vs_make_lists
      SET fileUrl = ${escapeSqlString(fileUrl)}, winnerCount ='${
      resultGet[0].winnerCount ? resultGet[0].winnerCount + 1 : 1
    }'
      WHERE list_id = ${id}
    `;

    return execSQL(sql);
  }

  return;
};



const escapeSqlString = (str) => {
  return mysql.escape(str);
};
```

Issues:

1. Parsing JSON using JSON.parse(resGetWC[0].fileUrl)
2. Adding the winnerCount field using reduce
3. Calling updateWinner with JSON.stringify(tempFileUrl)
4. When inserting into the database, the fileUrl JSON field does not contain the winnerCount field
5. When calling again, the fileUrl JSON field contains the winnerCount field

The problem is not reproduced in the local database but occurs online.

**console.log**
[image]

**use navicat connect mysql**
[image]

Comment: I bet you'll see your problem immediately if you do `console.log(sql)` right before `execSQL`.

Comment: Absoultely I try this way,  `console.log(sql)` there's  winnerCount filed but I use navicat connect mysql there's no winnerCount field. @O.Jones

Comment: I upload screen shots @O.Jones